# How to make a vs 2008 template out of the current project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to turn the current project which I've setted up nicely (project settings, additional libraries, and so on) into a project template in vs 2008 ?

How would one go about that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File -> Export Template -> Project Template

This will then appear under "My Templates" in VS

Comment: Of course ... it had to be obvious for me not to see it :-) Thank you.

Comment: ‘Export Template’ not Visible in Menu http://allthingsdotnet.net/523/export-template-not-visible-in-menu

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185291.aspx